# How to insert raw array into excell using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to insert array data into an excel file, I have already done it but I need a comma for every item of an array.

**this is my code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd_berat_badan_laki_laki = pd.read_excel("Tabel Antropometri Laki-Laki.xlsx", sheet_name='Berat badan menurut umur')
pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki = pd.read_excel("Tabel Antropometri Laki-Laki.xlsx", sheet_name='Panjang badan menurut umur')

array_berat_laki_min_3SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['-3 SD'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_min_2SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['-2 SD'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_min_1SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['-1 SD'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_min_median = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['Median'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_plus_1SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['+1 SD'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_plus_2SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['+2 SD'].to_numpy()
array_berat_laki_plus_3SD = pd_berat_badan_laki_laki['+3 SD'].to_numpy()

array_panjang_badan_laki_min_3SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['-3 SD'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_min_2SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['-2 SD'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_min_1SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['-1 SD'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_min_median = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['Median'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_1SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['+1 SD'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_2SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['+2 SD'].to_numpy()
array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_3SD = pd_panjang_badan_laki_laki['+3 SD'].to_numpy()

dict_antropometri_berat_laki = {
    '-3 SD':np.array(array_berat_laki_min_3SD), '-2 SD':np.array(array_berat_laki_min_2SD), '-1 SD': np.array(array_berat_laki_min_1SD), 
    'Median':np.array(array_berat_laki_min_median),
    '+1 SD':np.array(array_berat_laki_plus_1SD), '+2 SD':np.array(array_berat_laki_plus_2SD), '+3 SD':np.array(array_berat_laki_plus_3SD)
}

dict_antropometri_panjang_badan_laki = {
    '-3 SD':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_min_3SD), '-2 SD':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_min_2SD), '-1 SD': np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_min_1SD), 
    'Median':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_min_median),
    '+1 SD':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_1SD), '+2 SD':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_2SD), '+3 SD':np.array(array_panjang_badan_laki_plus_3SD)
}


df_arr_berat_antropometri_laki = pd.DataFrame([dict_antropometri_berat_laki])
df_arr_panjang_badan_antropometri_laki = pd.DataFrame([dict_antropometri_panjang_badan_laki])

writer_antropometri_laki = pd.ExcelWriter('Tabel Array Antropometri Laki-Laki.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df_arr_berat_antropometri_laki.to_excel(writer_antropometri_laki, sheet_name='Berat badan menurut umur', index=False)
df_arr_panjang_badan_antropometri_laki.to_excel(writer_antropometri_laki, sheet_name='Panjang badan menurut umur', index=False)

writer_antropometri_laki.save()
```

The result ends up like this

[image]

but I need the comma of every array item on my cell like this

```
[2.2, 2.3, 3.4, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do string formatting first before assigning the arrays to the dictionaries?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a_stringified = ', '.join([str(_) for _ in a])
>>> a_stringified
'1, 2, 3'
```

And then assign that instead?

Your code isn't exactly DRY (it repeats itself a lot), so it'll be a lot of typing. Maybe invest in making things more generic, too?